# Windows Universal App Javascript save file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I try to make app but i have one problem. How to save file or progress? If user have entered some information in app or changed it layout how it can be saved in universal javascript app? Now if i close app and open it again nothing have been saved

I have finded following but still i don't get it
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212883.aspx

So main question it's how to make universal app with javascript and save changes what user have made

[App image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah25H.png)

EDIT: There is picture of my app. I added also html code and javascript

**HTML:**

```
<div id="myDIV" class="header">
    <h2 style="margin:5px">My To Do List</h2>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Title...">
    <span id ="addtask" onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
</div>

<ul id="myUL">
    <li class="checked">Example checked</li>
    <li>Example not checked</li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
var myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
    var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
    var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
    span.className = "close";
    span.appendChild(txt);
    myNodelist[i].appendChild(span);
}


var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].onclick = function () {
        var div = this.parentElement;
        div.style.display = "none";
    }
}


var list = document.querySelector('ul');
list.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
    if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
        ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
    }
}, false);


var addlist = document.getElementById("addtask");
addlist.addEventListener("click", newElement, false);

function newElement() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
    li.appendChild(t);
    if (inputValue === '') {
        alert("You must write something!");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
    }
    document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";

    var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
    var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
    span.className = "close";
    span.appendChild(txt);
    li.appendChild(span);

    for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
        close[i].onclick = function () {
            var div = this.parentElement;
            div.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question appears too broad. It is unlikely that someone would like to do all the work for you. You need to provide some results of your own work on this problem - in code and clearly explain what's the problem with.

Comment: @EduardMalakhov better?

Comment: So, where are you trying to save data to a file?

Comment: @EduardMalakhov Local computer or is there other possibilities? Example open app in my mobile phone and add one item and then close it. Then i open it again and that one item still exists. I don't have any idea how i could code that

Comment: I meant, where is the code that you expect to do the saving?

Comment: @EduardMalakhov I haven't any code about that. I am not sure is it even possible to do :/. Only code's what i have tried is in that microsoft link

Comment: Please, check this example: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/FileAccess/js/js/scenario3_WriteAndReadTextInAFile.js

Answer (score 0):

> How to save file or progress

If you just want to create a file and save data to the file please reference [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files). And there is a file operation relative [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/FileAccess/js) writing in javascript you can reference.

But in my opinion you requirements look like more like you want a database. The database can save the data user changed and the app can also read data from the database to show on the app's one page. So you may need to use SQLite database on your app. Details for how to do you can reference [this document](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/02/06/using-sqlite-databases-uwp-apps/#rFctPkaeLr0JfLOi.97). Pay attention that this is recommended for local database, for roaming data you may consider using a server.

If you just want to save simple user data in the local device you may also consider using a xml file as a small database and store it in the [local](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.ApplicationData#Windows_Storage_ApplicationData_LocalFolder) folder. Saving and reading data changes from the xml file. Details for how to read and save data for a xml file you can reference [this javascript official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XmlDocument/js).

For example you may have a xml content saved the user data as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<myNodelist>
  <li>
    <Text>The first to do item</Text>
    <span class="close">×</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <Text>The second to do item</Text>
    <span class="close">×</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <Text>Read a book</Text>
    <span class="close">×</span>
  </li>
</myNodelist>
```

Reading the `myNodelist` to show the data, insert a new `li` node for adding new record.